# Trouble proving Gaussian-like integral

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, gaussian-integral

I came across Gaussian integrals, and was trying to prove them myself. I proved the basics, but am stuck on the following

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-a(x-b)^2}dx = b \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

I am having trouble thinking of how to attack this problem. I am currently thinking integration by parts to get rid of the $x$, and then try and coerce the exponent into the general Gaussian integral form but was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: Substitution with $u=x-b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

If we make the substitution $y = x - b$, we get:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xe^{-a(x-b)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(y+b)e^{-ay^{2}}\mathrm{d}y \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}ye^{-ay^{2}}\mathrm{d}y + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}be^{-ay^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}be^{-ay^{2}}\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}

once the function $ye^{-ay^{2}}$ is odd. Thus we have:
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}be^{-ay^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\right)^{2} & = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}be^{-ay^{2}}\mathrm{d}y\right)\times\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}be^{-az^{2}}\mathrm{d}z\right)\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}b^{2}e^{-a(y^{2} + z^{2})}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}

Hence, if you make the change of variable $y = \rho\cos(\theta)$ and $z = \rho\sin(\theta)$, you are able to obtain the sought result. Hope this helps.